# Marketing Cloud: Query data extensions or date event to trigger a Journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder

I am trying to create an entry event for Contacts when the transaction date has been > 120 days or = equal to 120 days in the past.

Contacts are synced in a synchronized DE  The transaction date is stored in TransactionHeader as synchronized DE from SF. Contact.Id is subscriber key and Contact.Id is related to TransactionHeader.BilltoContact.

Transaction date is stored in the following format: 06 March 2018 13:00

I have create a data based event for this:

Data Extension Name: TransactionHeader
Contact Attributes: TransactionHeader.TransactionDate
Re-entry: Yearly
Date: 120 days after TransactionHeader.TransactionDate
Time:
12:00 AM
Time Zone
(GMT) Greenwich Mean Time : Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London

Contacts are not entering the journey and I ran out of options to think of. Is this even possible to achieve or should I create a daily query as entry event?

Comment: I would recommend creating a query automation to trigger the journey.  You mention the format of the data field above?  The Transaction Date field needs to have a "date" datatype in order to correctly query or filter the records.

Comment: Thanks for you comment David. I have gathered the following functions. Would this work?

SELECT Contact.Email, Contact.AccountId, Contact.Id, Contact.FirstName, Contact.LastName, Contact.OwnerId, Contact.ContactID__c, Contact.Salutation
FROM ENT.Contact
INNER JOIN ENT.TransactionHeader ON TransactionHeader.AccountId=Contact.AccountId
WHERE TransactionHeader.TransactionDate__c = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 120 DAY

Comment: Close, but I don't think "CURDATE() - INTERVAL 120 DAY" is proper T-SQL syntax.

Comment: Also, your query will return multiple rows for the same contact if they have more than one transaction.  Try using the 'distinct' in your select statement.